# Ruby not allowing to handle the response with null params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Transactions API which has some null params. Here is the response

```
{
   "id": "abadfasdfasdf",
   "object": "balance_transaction",
   "amount": 5000,
   "available_on": 1649376000,
   "created": 1648844766,
   "currency": "gbp",
   "description": null,
   "exchange_rate": null,
   "fee": 165,
   "fee_details": [
     {
       "amount": 165,
       "application": null,
       "currency": "gbp",
       "description": "Stripe processing fees",
       "type": "stripe_fee"
     }
   ],
   "net": 4835,
   "reporting_category": "charge",
   "source": "ch_3Kjr2nFmjcSyeVx51op4ENCE",
  "status": "pending",
   "type": "charge"
 }
```

NameError (undefined local variable or method `null' for main:Object)

Here is my code

```
def stripe_fees
    stripe_transaction = stripe_checkout_webhook_response

    balance_transaction_id = stripe_transaction.dig(:data, :object, :balance_transaction)

    balance_transaction = Stripe::BalanceTransaction.retrieve(
      "#{balance_transaction_id}",
      )

    transaction_fee = balance_transaction.dig(:fee)
  end
```

gives the following error
NameError (undefined local variable or method `null' for main:Object)

Comment: can you show what you're doing with that response? because that is a json (should be treated as a string), and looks like you treating it as hash.

Comment: basically, it is a stripe transaction balance object so I am trying to get fee value from this json.


def stripe_fees
    stripe_transaction = params

    balance_transaction_id = stripe_transaction.dig(:data, :object, :balance_transaction)

    balance_transaction = Stripe::BalanceTransaction.retrieve(
      "#{balance_transaction_id}",
      )

    processing_fees = balance_transaction
    processing_fees.dig(:fee)
end

Comment: ok. `Stripe::BalanceTransaction.retrieve` returns an object that you can work with. but looks like you copy pasted that response into code somewhere, and that breaks it. can you edit your question and put full trace.

Comment: ok, this method looks fine. it would be helpful to see the full error log. basically somewhere there is the equivalent of `eval('{"id": null}')` and it should be `JSON.parse('{"id": null}')`

Comment: Basically, this response is coming in the variable and I am unable to parse it in a single quote because ruby does not support a single quote interpolation.